# How to get the golden guns?

Tags: splatoon

I've been playing the heck out of this game for the past few days, and I noticed some players had some nice shiny golden guns.

What conditions do I need to fulfill in order to unlock these weapons? (Are the they tied to the story mode, Amiibo, etc.)?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You are able to get 3 gold weapons (which are just replicas of other weapons) by beating the final level in the amiibo stages. You get a different weapon for each amiibo. From my understanding, you get these weapons for these amiibos:

- Inkling Girl - Gold Charger
- Inkling Boy - Gold Roller
- Squid - Gold Splattershot

Comment: This information is all incorrect.

Comment: The amiibo challenges are how you get the hero replica weapons, not gold weapons.

Comment: @Pyritie this has been made painfully aware to me.

Answer (score 15):

You can get the **[Gold Dynamo Roller](http://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Gold_Dynamo_Roller)** by defeating the final boss and taking his scroll blueprints. You need to reach level 20 to be able to buy the weapon, though.

To get the **[Aerospray RG](http://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Aerospray_RG)** (the golden rapid fire gun) you have to beat the Octowhirl and reach level 13 to be able to buy it.

The amiibos do not unlock golden weapons. They unlock replicas of the weapons used in single player (Hero Splat Roller Replica etc.)

Comment: They are still golden guns all the same. Your answer would probably be best served edited into mine to make a better, overall answer.

Comment: @Seiyria They are not gold. They are black with light blue spots and neon yellow stripes.

Comment: Here are the weapons Jaska is referring to: [Aerospray RG](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/splatoon/images/0/0e/Aerospray_rg.png/revision/latest) and [Gold Dynamo Roller](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/splatoon/images/d/d9/Golddynamoroller.png/revision/latest).

Comment: Here are the Hero Replica weapons that are unlocked via amiibo: [Hero Shot Replica](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/splatoon/images/1/15/Splatter_1.png/revision/latest), [Hero Roller Replica](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/splatoon/images/7/74/Roller_1.png/revision/latest), and [Hero Charger Replica](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/splatoon/images/2/29/Charger_1.png/revision/latest)